# Sylow theorem in fraighle's text

Tags: sylow-theory

I've been struggling with the first Sylow theorem.
Then γ−1[K] is a subgroup of N[H] and hence of G. This subgroup contains H and is of order pi+1 How come it has order pi+1, Couldn't understand that part. I've came across this in the proof of the First Sylow Theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Rax.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have $\gamma : N[H] \rightarrow N[H]/H$.

Now $K$ is a subgroup of order $p$ of $N[H]/H$, and $H$ has order $p^i$, so $\gamma^{-1}(K)$ has order $p \times p^i = p^{i+1}$.